# How can I set up MathJax to work with angular (throughout the entire project, and not just a specific component)?

Tags: angular, module, mathjax, asciimath

I have some asciimath text on my angular page and would like any asciimath, delimited by backticks `` to
i.e.: `sum_(i=1)^n i^3=((n(n+1))/2)^2` in these backticks, should be picked up by the MathJax library and converted into math annotation

[image]

I have installed:

```
npm install mathjax
npm install mathjax-full
npm install mathjax-angular
```

And I am trying to somehow set up my app.component.ts file according to this vague [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-angular).

How to import `MathjaxModule.forRoot(/*Optional Config*/)` with the specific config required to make this work for asciimath?

I don't see anything like this in the official [asciimath support](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html).

Comment: isn't `<div [mathjax]="content"></div>` the example you were looking for?